# RW locks with CRUD operations

Tags: go, mutex

I'm not sure if I'm approaching this right, the idea is to have concurrency while reading but lock only when it's writing or updating or deleting.

```
type Data struct {
    sync.RWMutex
    fooMap map[string]Foo
}

func (d *Data) AddFoo(foo Foo) {
    d.Lock()
    defer d.Unlock()

    d.fooMap[foo.getName()] = foo
}

func (d *Data) GetFoo(name string) Foo {
    return d.fooMap[name]
}

func (d *Data) RemoveFoo(name string) Foo {
    d.Lock()
    defer d.Unlock()

    var foo = self.fooMap[name]
    if foo != nil {
        delete(d.fooMap, name)
    }
    return foo
}

func (d *Data) HasFoo(name string) bool {
    return d.fooMap[name] != nil
}
```

Looking for an efficient approach where I don't block when I'm reading from the dictionary but block only in `AddFoo` and `RemoveFoo` methods.

**Edit**
The context is slightly different, the code will not be executed by `goroutines` but will be used on a server where I've tons of concurrent requests going on.

**Edit 2** In case of two maps

```
type Data struct {
    sync.RWMutex
    BarMutex sync.RWMutex{}
    fooMap map[string]Foo
    barMap map[string]Bar
}

// for Foo
func (d *Data) AddFoo(foo Foo) {
    d.Lock()
    defer d.Unlock()

    d.fooMap[foo.getName()] = foo
}

func (d *Data) GetFoo(name string) Foo {
    return d.fooMap[name]
}

// for Bar
func (d *Data) AddBar(bar Bar) {
    d.BarMutex.Lock()
    defer d.BarMutex.Unlock()

    d.barMap[bar.getName()] = bar
}

func (d *Data) GetBar(name string) Bar {
    d.BarMutex.RLock()
    defer d.BarMutex.RUnlock();
    return d.barMap[name]
}
```

Adding some more methods.

Comment: "the code will not be executed by goroutines but will be used on a server where I've tons of concurrent requests" if they're concurrent, they're in goroutines. You need to add `d.RLock();defer d.RUnlock()` to your `GetFoo` and `HasFoo` or you risk a data race with reads happening concurrently to writes.

Comment: Note though that if you share data, you will have to block on some reads if they happen concurrently to writes. You can't "block only in AddFoo and RemoveFoo methods", that's not how synchronization works.

Comment: @Adrian, if you can incorporate your comments into a code in an answer, happy to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the code will not be executed by goroutines but will be used on a server where I've tons of concurrent requests

If they're concurrent, they're in goroutines - for example, if you're using the `net/http` server, every request is in its own goroutine. There are no other concurrency mechanisms, so if you've got concurrency, you're using goroutines, even if your code doesn't explicitly start them.

You can't "block only in AddFoo and RemoveFoo methods"; that's not how synchronization works. If you share data, you will have to acquire a lock for reads, and you will block on some reads if they happen concurrently to writes. If you don't acquire a lock for reads, you have a race condition.

```
func (d *Data) GetFoo(name string) Foo {
    d.RLock()
    d.RUnlock()
    return d.fooMap[name]
}
```

The alternative would be to *share memory by communicating*. This is a more complex refactor and there are many ways of doing it depending on your specific needs; it's not something I could offer a solution for based on a "Foo" type generic example.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, I really appreciate. I'd like to learn more on this sharing memory by communicating, sounds like message passing to me, is there an example link that you can share.

Comment: It is message passing, and there are many ways to accomplish it; I'm not sure of a single link that would give you all the reasonable options but I'm sure a web search would turn up a wealth of information.

Comment: a slight twist if you don't mind, if I've two maps in `type Data{}`, the second one being `barMap map[string]Bar`, with it's own set of `Get` and `Add` methods, how do I lock either one individually?

Comment: Use a separate `RWMutex` for each map.

Comment: Though if that is your use case, you should at least consider just having two separate types (one for holding `Foo`s and one for holding `Bar`s), and composing them into a combined type if you universally use them together. It would probably make them easier to work with in the long run.

Comment: Your second point is valid, however, I'm porting this library to go and deviating from original is problem for me, I did attempt with **edit 2**, is that how it's supposed to be? please review.

Comment: That seems fine, though you might want to go ahead and name both mutexes instead of one being named and one embedded, just to avoid confusion.

Comment: got it, thanks again, really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Have you looked at http://github.com/jwells131313/goethe, which has recursive read/write locks.  We use it for cases just like this